# Dynamic Variable Names with JavaScript - Two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I'm trying to generate markers for every user in my $.each loop in such a way that I can select each marker using the corresponding `userId` of a given user.

```
$.each($.parseJSON(window.usersArray), function (i, user) {
    window.userMarkers[user['id']] = L.marker(98.76, 12.34).addTo(map);
    console.log(window.userMarkers[user['id']]);
});
```

**EDIT**

I get the error:
`Cannot set property '3' of undefined`, where `3` is the user's ID.

Comment: user['id'] ? should be user[i]

Comment: are you getting a console error? What is `L.marker(98.76, 12.34).addTo(map);` and why does it have nothing to do with `user`?

Comment: You do know there's a missing `);` in the end, right?

Comment: Still wrong. The last line should be `});`, not `)}`.

Comment: ahhh sorry - no, the `user['id']` comes from my database and is an actual user's unique ID - in other words it's totally independent of `i` here. And `L.marker(98.76, 12.34).addTo(map);` is just the code that adds the marker to the map in Leaflet - I wasn't sure if I should remove it or not. And yes, you're right, I forgot the `);`, added it in. Validating from now on!

Comment: What about the error? What are you getting and what did you want to get?

Comment: What does `addTo` return ?  If nothing this is expected behavior. Also I'm not sure what $.each is in this context but most each functions have the value as the first argument not the index.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @pllee, that is kinda weird. Nonetheless it works - I'm just modifying my working `$.each` loop to incorporate naming these markers according to which users they represent, instead of just creating them without names. `addTo()` just adds the marker to the map.

Comment: Thanks for posting the error message. Obviously this means that `window.userMarkers` is `undefined` and you are trying to set properties on it. Show us where you defined `userMarkers`!

Comment: I suppose I didn't! I just assumed it was created automatically. Same error after adding 'window.userMarkers;' above the $.each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the object (or array depending on your needs) before you can add anything to it.

```
window.userMarkers = {};

$.each($.parseJSON(window.usersArray), function (i, user) {
    window.userMarkers[user['id']] = L.marker(98.76, 12.34).addTo(map);
    console.log(window.userMarkers[user['id']]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Define the array before setting properties to it! Example:

window.userMarkers = new Array();

Comment: Don't use `new Array()` use `[]`.  Also, if the keys can be non-numeric or are very sparse, you probably want to use an object instead as in my answer using `{}` to initialize it.